# How to request details about more then one url in a single fql query?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-fql

I made a fql query that returns details about a single url. At this point I create a new query for each page on the site - this obivously isn't very efficiant. Is there a way to create one query that returns all the pages and their details.
For example:
What I get now:

```
<fql_query_response xmlns="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" list="true">
<link_stat>
<url>www.facebook.com</url>
<normalized_url>http://www.facebook.com/</normalized_url>
<share_count>50783153</share_count>
<like_count>2482551</like_count>
<comment_count>2371768</comment_count>
<total_count>55637472</total_count>
<commentsbox_count>0</commentsbox_count>
<comments_fbid>10150187081535131</comments_fbid>
<click_count>243646</click_count>
</link_stat>
</fql_query_response>
```

What I need:

```
<fql_query_response xmlns="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" list="true">
<link_stat>
<url>www.facebook.com</url>
<normalized_url>http://www.facebook.com/</normalized_url>
<share_count>50783153</share_count>
<like_count>2482551</like_count>
<comment_count>2371768</comment_count>
<total_count>55637472</total_count>
<commentsbox_count>0</commentsbox_count>
<comments_fbid>10150187081535131</comments_fbid>
<click_count>243646</click_count>
</link_stat>

<link_stat>
<url>www.yahoo.com</url>
<normalized_url>http://www.yahoo.com/</normalized_url>
<share_count>50783153</share_count>
<like_count>2482551</like_count>
<comment_count>2371768</comment_count>
<total_count>55637472</total_count>
<commentsbox_count>0</commentsbox_count>
<comments_fbid>10150187081535131</comments_fbid>
<click_count>243646</click_count>
</link_stat>
</fql_query_response>
```

Comment: What does your query look like? Have you tried using the IN() operator already?

Comment: this is the query with th IN() operator, It returns only the facebook.com response (I might be doing it wrong, i'm new to fql):    https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count, commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM link_stat WHERE url IN 'www.facebook.com, www.yahoo.com'

Comment: You’re not using the IN operator correctly – right now you are asking for _one_ URL that is `'www.facebook.com, www.yahoo.com'` – which of course doesn’t exist. What you _want_ to do is ask for URLs that equal one of _several different_ choices: `WHERE url IN ('www.facebook.com', 'www.yahoo.com')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to close this question so its marked as resolved.

to recap, you just had some problem with your IN() and your quoting on string of the domains

```
 IN('www.facebook.com, www.yahoo.com')
```

should be

```
 IN('www.facebook.com', 'www.yahoo.com')
```

http://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20url,%20normalized_url,%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count,%20commentsbox_count,%20comments_fbid,%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url%20IN('www.facebook.com',%20'www.yahoo.com')